# Concatenate Numpy ndarray to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas dataframe (d6_y_data_test) which I have just conducted a statistical test on a number of its columns and the results of this test by observation are output in a Numpy NDarray (d8_y_probs). I would like to concatenate the results in the NDarray to the Pandas Dataframe but am having all sorts of trouble:

The first thing I tried is just concatenating them as you would two dataframes:

```
f2_error_model = pd.concat([d6_y_data_test, d8_y_probs])
```

and I get

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

So I have tried turning d8_y_probs into a dataframe doing the below for some reason makes each data point into its own column rather than row:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([d8_y_probs])
```

So does anyone know how I can concatenate the Numpy NDArray d8_y_probs to the Pandas DataFrame d6_y_data_test?

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to put `d8_y_probs` into a column? Does `d6_y_data_test['y_probs'] = d8_y_probs.flatten()` not work?